# Does it exist a Weblogic plug-in for Java Mission Control 7.1.2?

Tags: weblogic, jmc

The previous version of JDK Mission Control 5.5.2 bundled with Oracle JDK 7 had the possibility to add a WebLogic plug-in, which allows viewing the SQL queries, servlets between other components as seen in this image.
[image: Weblogic plug-in for JMC5.5.2]

Then the new JDK Mission Control 7.1.2+b04 doesn't seem to have a similar plug-in or at least it's more complicated to apply it.

When trying to investigate, the JMC is pointing to
https://download.oracle.com/technology/products/missioncontrol/updatesites/oracle/7.1.2/ide/update-site-instructions/index.html
stating that the plugin must be installed via Eclipse 4.8 or later, so the latest Eclipse is 2012-12 was installed, and then the plugin with https://download.oracle.com/technology/products/missioncontrol/updatesites/oracle/7.1.2/ide/ as well, as seen in this image:
[image]

The Eclipse IDE was restarted and now it got a new icon in the menu bar:
[image: Icons bar with the new JMC connector]

which connects (or at least it tries to connect) with the Java processes running in this local station:
[image]

but that's not the WebLogic plug-in I expected, similar to the one available in the previous version of JMC.

Does it exist a WebLogic plug-in in JMC7.1.2 similar to the existing in JMC5.5.2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To install WebLogic plug-in for JMC, go to Help menu and select Install New Software menu item. Expand "Mission Control (Oracle)" and then "Flight Recorder" and you will find "WebLogic Pages" plug-in. Follow the instructions on screen to complete installation of plug-in.

[image: Screengrab of plugin installation window]

This is described in the [Oracle JMC 7 User Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/doc/JDMUG/preface.htm) under [Install JMC Standalone Application](https://docs.oracle.com/javacomponents/doc/JDMUG/installing-jdk-mission-control-and-supported-plugins.htm#JDMUG-GUID-90F51251-D79E-499D-9475-140FE1926810) in the "Install Plug-ins for JMC Standalone Application" sub-section.

Comment: I had a connectivity issue while using the VPN, thus the list of plug-ins under the "Available Software" screen was empty. Once the VPN was disconnected and using direct connection (Preferences > Network Connections > Direct), JMC was able to contact the server and pull the plug-in. Now it's installed. Thank you very much for responding!